# Xamarin.Android MvxListView recycling

Tags: memory, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, mvxbind

Does `MvxListView` support recycling by default? Early I used simple `ListView` and wrote custom `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` for more productivity. But now I want use `MvxListView` (MvvmCross) and Binding. But scrolling is very slow and lag.

Comment: I recommend using `MvxRecyclerView` instead. And if you're using images and the ImageUrl binding, that's the reason for the lag

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa if my application need support Android 4.1 - `MvxRecyclerView` doesn't supported, because it inherited from Android native `RecyclerView` which stay become available from Android 5.0. + Yes, you are right - I am using images in template, but if I use view holders and simple `ListView` - it is more smoother

Comment: RecyclerView is available from API 7 so you can use this in your 4.1 app.

Comment: @Martijn00, thanks you! I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `MvxRecyclerView`. The code and sample for it can be found here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView

Comment: cannot able to reach to the link?